# Too much space between title lines? Vspace does not work

Tags: beamer

I want to create a beamer presentation and I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title[Value at Risk, Name1, Name2{\&} Nam3]{Calculate the Value at Risk \tiny \\using the Delta-Normal model, nonparametric methods,\\ MonteCarlo simulations and historical sim



University\\
\vskip1em

Chair\\
Chairholder: Name\\
Supervisor: Name\\
%\vskip1em
%\vskip1em
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{12,013,148}
\textcolor{darkblue}{\textit{Course description}}

 \small
Place, July 2013\\

\footnotesize
\textit{$^1$$^{, 2}$ Master ,  Semester}}
%\textit{$^2$ Master,  Semester}}
\normalsize


% Comment the following command, if you don't want, that the pdf file starts in full screen mode:
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

%Start of the document
\begin{document}


 \frame{
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries \begingroup\color{blue} 1)\endgroup]
\item Test
\item Test
\end{enumerate}


}
\end{document}
```

So now, you see the title is very long and I need some linebreaks, but the space is too much and if I try:

```
 \title[Value at Risk, Name1, Name2{\&} Nam3]{Calculate the Value at Risk \tiny \\using the Delta-Normal model, nonparametric methods,\\ MonteCarlo simulations and historical simulations}
```

does not work. How can I get this?

(I used the extra footnotes, since the normal in \authora did not work)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The commands `\authora` and similar are not defined in standard `beamer`. Moreover, the document is empty, so no output is generated. Can you fix the example?

Comment: @egreg ok I did so.

Comment: Sorry, but the document doesn't compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you replace `\\` by `\newline{}` (and add `\maketitle` right after `\begin{document}`).

Also, the `\normalsize` in your preamble is not required / wrong.

Finally, note that your code is strongly abusing the LaTeX syntax: `\title` is meant for the title, not for your whole titlepage information. I do not know `beamer` that well (read the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)!), but authors for example should be given using the `\author` command.
The following code shows how to make it more structured, but it can surely still be improved:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{12,013,148}

\title{Value at Risk}
\subtitle{\small Calculation using the Delta-Normal model, nonparametric methods, MonteCarlo and historical simulations}
\author{\tiny%
  University XYZ\\
  Chair\\
  Chairholder: Name\thanks{Chairholder detail}\\
  Supervisor: Name\thanks{Supervisor detail}\\[1em]
  \textcolor{darkblue}{\textit{Course description}}}
\date{Place, July 2013}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frame{
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries \begingroup\color{blue} 1)\endgroup]
    \item Test
    \item Test
  \end{enumerate}}

\end{document}
```

The `\small` in the code is to show how to easily control output size. Replace it by whatever you prefer and/or use the same for `\author` or other similar commands.